# Delete Record using GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have some problem in delete record. I use VB.net with Access Database. When I try to run this program there have no error but the record didn't delete in database. There are one class to delete record and this class will called another method which is call DeleteMultipleRecords. Here is my code, hope anyone can help me to solve this.

**-Default.aspx.vb-**

```
Protected Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    'create string collection to store IDs of records to be deleted
    Dim idCollection As New StringCollection()
    Dim strID As String = String.Empty
    'Loop through GridView rows to find checked rows 
    For i As Integer = 0 To i < GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim chkDelete As CheckBox = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("chkSelect"), CheckBox)
        If chkDelete IsNot Nothing Then
            If chkDelete.Checked Then

                strID = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text
                idCollection.Add(strID)

            End If
        End If
    Next

    'called method to delete record
    DeleteMultipleRecords(idCollection)

    'rebind(GridView)
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
Private Sub DeleteMultipleRecords(ByVal idCollection As StringCollection)
    'create connection
    Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection(strConnection)
    Dim IDs As String = ""

    'create string builder to store 
    'delete commands seperated by ;

    For Each id As String In idCollection

        IDs += id.ToString() & ","
    Next

    Try

        Dim strIDs As String = IDs.Substring(0, IDs.LastIndexOf(""))
        Dim strSql As String = ("Delete from Details WHERE ID = '" & strIDs & "' ")

        cmdOLEDB.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdOLEDB.CommandText = strSql
        cmdOLEDB.Connection = cnnOLEDB
        cnnOLEDB.Open()
        cmdOLEDB.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmdOLEDB.Dispose()

    Catch ex As OleDbException

        Dim errorMsg As String = "Error in Deletion"
        errorMsg += ex.Message
        Throw New Exception(errorMsg)

    Finally
        cnnOLEDB.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

**-Default.aspx-**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID"/>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" 
                   SortExpression="Name">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" 
             Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'  ReadOnly="true" 
             BorderStyle="none" 
             BorderWidth="0px" >
</asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location" 
                   SortExpression="Location">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" 
             Text='<%# Bind("Location") %>' 
             ReadOnly="true" 
             BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
</asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LabSystemDBConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LabSystemDBConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Details]"
        DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [Details] WHERE ID = [@ID]">

    <DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
    </DeleteParameters></asp:SqlDataSource>


    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" OnClientClick="return DeleteConfirmation();"  Text="Delete" />
    &nbsp;<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change these lines to work:

```
For Each id As String In idCollection

    IDs += "'" + id.ToString() & "',"
Next

Try

    Dim strIDs As String = IDs.Substring(0, IDs.LastIndexOf(""))
    Dim strSql As String = ("Delete from Details WHERE ID IN (" & strIDs & ")")
```

**BUT**: this code is prone to [SQL INJECTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), you must use SQL parameters in 2012.

Comment: I already change but it still same, no error but it didn't delete the record

Answer (score 0):

Please set a break point at

```
Dim strSql As String = ("Delete from Details WHERE ID IN (" & strIDs & ")")
```

then run your application, and add watch to strSql, when the breakpoint is hit, press F11, then you can see the content of strSql, copy that sql statment and run the query in your Access Database, and see if it is working.

PS: try to add [] to table names, DELETE FROM [Details]